# Local socket for PostgreSQL in Racket (db.plt)

Tags: postgresql, scheme, racket

can somebody please explain to me, why this code gives me an error?

```
(require (planet "main.rkt" ("ryanc" "db.plt" 1 2)))
(postgresql-connect #:user "dsp" #:database "getmea" #:socket (postgresql-guess-socket-path))
```

> Scheme->C: expects argument of type `<path>`; given `#<void>`

```
> (postgresql-guess-socket-path)
"/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
> (path-string? "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432")
#t
```

Comment: I have a feeling the error is elsewhere. Try using `#:socket 'guess` and see what you get. If the error is still there, your problem is not with the `#:socket` value. You would need to post more code.

Comment: I get exactly the same error.

Comment: Then, the error isn't in what you've pasted so far. Please include the rest of your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error was in the library. I've uploaded a fixed version.